# Assigning NSUInteger to BOOL conceptual understanding

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to look for a good answer to the concept of BOOL. As I understand, a zero is a false value, and non-zero is a true value. Thinking this I assigned string length into a BOOL variable. Now, this works fine for iOS > 6. On iOS 6 I see strange results. For string with odd length, isEnabled is turing True but for strings with even length, isEnabled is turing False.

```
BOOL isEnabled = myString.length;
```

Please help me understand this. Of course, now I've been assigning expressions to BOOL variable like this:

```
BOOL isEnabled = myString.length > 0;
```

Exact code:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)iTextView {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = [[self.noteTextView.text trim] length];
}
```

PS: As mentioned, myString is changing in length; from 'a' to 'ab' to 'abc' etc.

Comment: what is the value of myString ?

Comment: Please see the edit above.

Comment: edited ans. please see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I could not understand the iOS 6 behaviour for enabling the button for odd ones only. [...] I was curious to know the root cause.

To explain the observed behavior there are two technical details to explain: The type of Objective-C's `BOOL` and implementation details of UIKit.

#### Type of `BOOL`

The differing behavior is actually not related to the iOS *version* but to the device's *architecture*. There's a difference on how the iOS SDK defines a BOOL for 32 versus 64 bit architectures. See this excerpt from `objc.h`:

```
#if !defined(OBJC_HIDE_64) && TARGET_OS_IPHONE && __LP64__
typedef bool BOOL;
#else
typedef signed char BOOL; 
#endif
```

So `BOOL` on 32 bit can have any value between 0 and 255, while on 64 bit it is compiler enforced to only have the values 0 or 1. You can easily try this by running the following line on the simulator, set to iPhone 4s (32 bit) or iPhone 6 (64 bit).

```
NSLog(@"%d", (BOOL)2);
```

This is the explanation for why you see differing behavior on different devices. But where does the even-odd thing come from?

#### Implementation details of UIBarButtonItem

There's another subtle technical detail involved. You are actually setting the `enabled` property of a `UIBarButtonItem`.

Apple likes to use a space saving scheme to store flags in their UI components. A `BOOL` (on both 32 and 64 bit architectures) would always use at least one byte, but only one bit of information is needed. So they are using [bit fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) to store the actual value.

Excerpt from iOS SDK 8.4 `UIBarButtonItem.h` (shortened for clarity):

```
@interface UIBarButtonItem : UIBarItem {
    struct {
        unsigned int enabled:1;
    } _barButtonItemFlags;
}
```

The magic is the `:1` behind the `enabled` field in the `_barButtonItemFlags` struct. This defines the bit-field of width one. To connect the `enabled` property with this bit-field, they have to implement custom accessors. Here's an example for the setter:

```
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
    _barButtonItemFlags.enabled = enabled;
}
```

So what happens when we're doing this:

```
someBarButtonItem.enabled = 2;
```

The compiler understands that it has to call the `setEnabled:` method with an argument of 2.

On 64 bit architectures the `2` would be converted to `_Bool`, where the standard says this has to result in a value of `1`. On 32 bit systems this is not the case, leaving the original value of `2` in place, before calling the method.

Inside of `setEnabled:` the value is assigned to an `unsigned int` of width 1. The C standard says that when assigning an unsigned integer of greater width the remaining bits are just dropped. The result is that `setEnabled:` just stores the lowest bit of the argument in `_barButtonItemFlags.enabled`. The lowest bit is one on odd numbers, zero on even numbers.

#### Conclusion

All of the above behavior is within the semantics provided by the standard. There is no undefined behavior involved. It's just an unfortunate fact that the expected behavior of `BOOL` differs from what you actually get on 32 bit architectures.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

In earlier times `BOOL` was implemented as an integer type. Therefore it was possible with such an *implementation* to assign a value > 1 to it and reading it back. But this had been wrong (because relying on an implementation detail) from the very beginning, because the documentation always said that the valid values for an (C) object of type `BOOL` are `NO` and `YES`. Period.

Starting in 2014(? 2013?) the `BOOL` type became more like the C `_Bool` type. That means that assigning a value > 1 to an object of that type, 1 (`YES`) is stored into the variable. So, in any case the behavior changed. (An undefined behavior became a defined behavior and the behavior is different to the older undefined one.)

But your problem looks like that only Bit0 is stored. (It is 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd number.) This would be a bug. Please show us the complete code.

However, you can use `_Bool` instead of `BOOL`.

Comment: BOOL's behaviour was changed in 2012, I think. It seems likely to me that the project was somehow set to an older standard and targeting iOS 6 forced a newer standard to be used. I wasn't able to find out when `objc_bool` is unavailable.

Comment: Really 2012? As times goes by … However, that's not very important. Using `_bool` instead is the best solution, I think.

Comment: Actually, I think 2012 is probably when it went into clang not Xcode/clang. 2013 is probably right. :) Good description here: http://nshipster.com/bool/ Bottom line, though, is that if you're using modern Xcode and modern C `BOOL` is fine. At least I hope it is!

Comment: The comments on nshipster seem especially useful.

Comment: I do not like the explanations of NSHipster too much. (I think one has to stress that a value > 1 always had been an invalid value causing an undefined behavior. There are masses of such situations in C.) However, one should know his explanations.

Comment: Well, if BOOL is defined correctly using `objc_bool` the behaviour should be correct. And if one is treating non-zero BOOL values as YES (without requiring `== YES`) it should be correct. But those are pretty high requirements, and the best option is probably to write the comparison as `myString.length > 0`.

Comment: Reading all this again, I wonder if the difference between iOS 5 & 6 is that `setEnabled` was changed in iOS 6 to not assume that only `== YES` was true. Seems the most likely explanation here.

Comment: No, it should not be correct to treat a value > 1 as `YES`, because a value > 1 is illegal. Therefore using `== YES` should not be marked as a problem, but the fact that something else than { 0, 1 } is stored in the `BOOL` object. The advice, not to check on `YES` does not solve a (non) problem, but deepens the real problem somewhere else in the code. BTW: It is obviously  ridiculous to mark a comparison between an object and one of its legal values as problem. What next? Don't compare `int`s with 17?

Comment: However, I accepted that most developers agree with NSHipster, even I do not.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - What you mentioned is correct and I understood that. However, I could not understand the iOS 6 behaviour for enabling the button for odd ones only. I've pated the exact piece of code which is failing. Replacing it with a actual boolean expression fixes the issue but I was curious to know the root cause. It may be iOS 6 only issue as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this ,

```
    BOOL isEnabled;

    if ( ( myString.length % 2 ) == 0 ) {

        //Is even

    isEnabled=FALSE;

    }
    else {

        //Is odd
    isEnabled=TRUE;

    }
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what the question asks. :)