# Assign NSUInteger to UIButton enabled property not work in devices with 32 bit architecture

Tags: ios

Just come cross a strange bug in devices with 32 bit architecture,
below is the code:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    self.button.enabled = textView.text.length;
}
```

So whenever I paste some text whose length is not 1 into the textView, 
(this is to imitate the behaviour of a third-party keyboard [Sogou](https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/sou-gou-shu-ru-fa-quan-hao/id917670924?mt=8)), the button will not be enabled.

You can use this [Demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0mm9lwladugk55q/Demo.zip?dl=0) to reproduce the bug.

I've read related posts, like [Assigning NSUInteger to BOOL conceptual understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982311/assigning-nsuinteger-to-bool-conceptual-understanding), but this case is different.

Please tell me why it does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as a bug. Think of it as your code being wrong. This line is horrible:

```
self.button.enabled = textView.text.length;
```

You are trying to misuse a number as a BOOL. You are thus assuming that any non-zero number is the same as `YES`. That is a false assumption. Stop writing code like that. Write it like this:

```
self.button.enabled = (textView.text.length > 0);
```

That way, the BOOL really *is* a BOOL.